# Wildcard not working in XLOOKUP function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to search an URL from list of URLs in Column A with `xlookup` (using wildcard), but it shows error "Did not find value 'https://forums.pcsx2.net/*' in XLOOKUP evaluation."

My formula is: `xlookup(A10&"*",A2:A7,A2:A7)`
[image]
I am attaching [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a7KBefvnwgLCG_agO2HTCQu6U3XYQAXSXiaAXl_9Zso/edit#gid=0) here for your reference.

Please guide me how to use wildcard match (*) in given example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xlookup` function has an optional parameter to enable wildcard searches.

Try this: `=xlookup(A10&"*",A2:A7,A2:A7,,2)`